# Different true/false definition in lambda calculus

Tags: logic, learning, lambda-calculus

How to deal with different definition *true/false*. In standard conception is true defined as taking the first value and false as taking the second one. 
Let's say we have true/false defined as follows:

$$true = \lambda xy.x \\false = \lambda xy.yx $$

Can you explain to me how to define $ \leq $? Now I don't want you to tell me the solution (which I post here) - I got a problem to figure out how to thought process tasks like this one. Is there any pattern for this stuff or is it something you can't learn (but need that right *intuition*)?

Solution(using ternary operator):

$$LET(?:) =\lambda ctf.ct(\lambda x.f)$$
$$LET (\leq)  =\lambda ab.iszero(sub (ab)) ? True:False $$ *(sub(ab))* stands for *(sub ab)*

Comment: You can see [Arithmetic in lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Arithmetic_in_lambda_calculus).

Comment: A *predicate* is a function taht returns a boolean : TRUE if the predicate holds of the values in input. Thus, $\text {LEQ}(m,n)$ must return TRUE if $m \le n$. Now, $\text {SUB}(m,n)$ is $m-n$ if $m > n$ and $0$ otherwise, and so we have that $\text {ISZERO}(\text {SUB}(m,n))$ returns TRUE if $\text {SUB}(m,n)$ returns $0$, i.e. if **not** $m > n$, i.e. iff $m \le n$.

Comment: Not clear the question anout TRUE/FALSE. It is a "convention": we map FALSE to $0$ and TRUE to $1$; similarly in lambda we define FALSE as $\lambda x. \lambda y. y$ that is the encoding of numeral $0$.

Comment: Well, it is convention. But in this example true/false is defined another way. Ok? Just take it as a fact. Don't think about that

Comment: @P.Barbra If you let yourself be inspired by what Mauro ALLEGRANZA states, you might recognize that the definition you've given for true and false defines true as the Church-encoding of $0$ and false as the Church-encoding of $1$. This alpha renaming may help: $true=\lambda zs.z$ and $false=\lambda zs.s(z)$. If you are comfortable working with Church numerals, then you just define a function that produces $0$ or $1$ as appropriate.

Comment: I think the poster is attempting to ask if there is an algorithm, given 2 lambda expressions T and F (probably need some decidable conditions), to find lambda expressions representing propositional logic operators.